# how to replace a strings in a file with delimited without effecting numericals?

Tags: shell-script

Input file:

```
123 exx abcdef 890 hello-hi-welcome and name in-India 1 3.45 1.3538 8.773
456 hfjgt 928 aetr-new-abc-India 1 9.7392 18.1903 8.752
```

Output:

```
123,exx abcdef,890,hello-hi-welcome and name in-India,1,3.45,1.3538,8.773
456,hfjgt,928,aetr-new-abc-India,1,9.7392,18.1903,8.752
```

How can we write a shell script for this?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: @mallesh, What is your algorithm for deciding which spaces to keep and which to convert to commas?

Answer (score 1):

I think is it sufficient to change a space either before or after a digit:

```
$ sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]) /\1,/g; s/ ([[:digit:]])/,\1/g' file
123,exx abcdef,890,hello-hi-welcome and name in-India,1,3.45,1.3538,8.773
456,hfjgt,928,aetr-new-abc-India,1,9.7392,18.1903,8.752
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to separate numbers and non-digit items in each line.

GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[^0-9]{2,}' '{ 
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
               gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$i); printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF? ORS:OFS) 
           } 
}' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
123,exx abcdef,890,hello-hi-welcome and name in-India,1,3.45,1.3538,8.773
456,hfjgt,928,aetr-new-abc-India,1,9.7392,18.1903,8.752
```